# Can I handle all errors through ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-error

I am trying to create a 404 handling page but I am now stuck with the page only working for .aspx files, which isn't really what I need.

I am running on IIS6. The site has a wildcard mapping, for extensionless URLs. All requests go through Application_BeginRequest in Global.asax but not all errors go through Application_Error.

Is there a way where I can get the Application_Error to raise for non .aspx files?

This is the code inside the Application_Error

```
HttpException serverError = (HttpException)Server.GetLastError();

if (serverError != null) {
    int errorCode = serverError.GetHttpCode();
    if (errorCode == 404) {
        Server.ClearError();
        Server.Transfer("/errorPage.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've successfully handled this with IIS 6 is to add a specific handler for 404 in IIS custom errors that points to one of your .aspx or .ashx files (i.e. point it to your errorPage.aspx).

Comment: When I tried that it redirected to errorPage.aspx. I need to to this to keep the same url in the browser and also return a 404 status code.

Comment: I understand now. You mentioned using URL rewriting above. If that's the case, what constitutes a 404 with your setup then? It sounds like you would need another rewrite rule that kicks in when all others fail. The last rule would rewrite to errorPage.aspx and that page would have to ensure that the status code 404 was sent to via the response.

Comment: I might be saying something stupid here, but wouldn't that interfere with requests done to pages I don't want to rewrite? You are saying that i should create a rule which basically matches any string. Is that correct?

Comment: That's not a stupid statement at all. I imagined you were rewriting everything in your application. If that's not the case, you do not want to add a catch-all rule, because, as you stated, it would prevent your physical pages from being executed.

Comment: Normally, the server's machine.config or master web.config is setup to handle physical pages via the PageHandlerFactory: <add path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" validate="True"/>. You could always create you own factory that inherits from PageHandlerFactory, remove the one above in your config via a <remove name="*.aspx" />, then add yours. Your factory's GetHandler method would call base.GetHandler and check the result for null. If null (a 404), you would create an instance of your errorPage and return it. Not ideal, but it should work.